# Progress bar/spinner not working in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, progress

I'm using an NSProgressIndicator and it only redraws after the main event loop.  The spinner however never starts or stops.  I am using the following code to start the progress indicator:

```
 [progressIndicator startAnimating];
```

It is also synthesized, and included properly in the .h and .m files.  I have connected it in IB.

The code doesn't seem to work for the progress bar or the spinner.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What exactly are you trying to do, and what isn't working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`startAnimating` isn't a method of `NSProgressIndicator`.  Try:

```
[progressIndicator startAnimation:self];
```

Also check out `setUsesThreadedAnimation:`, which might help you out.